# Mask field of column(struct type) in Spark DataFrame

Tags: xml, scala, apache-spark, dataframe, masking

I have a created a DataFrame from XML file. The created DataFrame has the below scheme.

```
val df = hiveContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.xml").option("rowTag", row_tag_name).load(data_dir_path_xml)

df.printSchema()

            root
             |-- samples: struct (nullable = true)
             |    |-- sample: array (nullable = true)
             |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
             |    |    |    |-- abc: string (nullable = true)
             |    |    |    |-- def: long (nullable = true)
             |    |    |    |-- type: string (nullable = true)
             |-- abc: string (nullable = true)
```

I would like to mask the abc/def in the dataframe.

I was able to get to the field i want using:

```
val abc = df.select($"samples.sample".getField("abc"))
```

But i want to mask  the field abc/def (replace abc field  with XXXX ) in the dataframe df. Please help me on this

Comment: what do you mean by mask abc/def? is it that you want to mask abc with def value?

Comment: I want to replace the fields 'abc' and 'def' with a value 'xxxxx'. Those fields are sensitive data.

Comment: you want to replace the column values right?

Comment: Exactly, I want to replace the values of the entire column, @RameshMaharjan

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be much, if any, support in the databricks xml library for manipulating the contents of an XML-based dataframe (wouldn't it be cool to be able to use XSLT?!). But you can always manipulate the inferred rows directly, e.g.

```
val abc = df.map(row => {
  val samples = row.getStruct(0).getSeq(0)
  val maskedSamples = samples.map(sample => {
     Row("xxxxx", sample.getLong(1), sample.getString(2))
  }
  Row(Row(maskedSamples), row.getString(1))
}
```

The code above may not precisely match your desired transformation, since it's somewhat unclear, but you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to split the `samples array` `structType` to separate `columns` (`StructFields`) so that you can mask/replace them as you want. And you can apply `dataframe functions` as well later on if you want.
Below is the code to separate into three columns

```
df.withColumn("abcd", lit($"samples.sample.abc"))
      .withColumn("def", lit($"samples.sample.def"))
      .withColumn("type", lit($"samples.sample.type"))
```

You can drop the `samples column` if you want

```
.drop("samples")
```

Since you want to mask `abc` and `def` with XXXX, you can do

```
df.withColumn("abcd", lit("XXXX"))
      .withColumn("def", lit("XXXX"))
      .withColumn("type", lit($"samples.sample.type"))
      .drop("samples")
```

**Note : `abcd column name` is used as there is already another `column` `abc` in your schema**

**Edited to meet the @Raj comments below:**
 
If the `original schema` is to be preserved and separate `columns` are not required then creation of a `case class` and a `udf` function should do the trick

```
def mask = udf((typ: mutable.WrappedArray[String]) => Raj("XXXXX", Option(0L), typ(0)))
```

`Case class` for `Raj` is needed

```
case class Raj(abc : String,
               dfe : Option[Long],
               typ: String)
```

Finally call the `udf` function by passing the `type` in `withColumn`

```
df.withColumn("samples", struct(array(mask(col("samples.sample.type"))) as "sample"))
```

This should get you the working output

Comment: I tried using df.withColumn. Doing so will create a dataframe with schema
           root
             |-- abcd: string (nullable = true)
             |-- def: long (nullable = true)
             |-- type: string (nullable = true)
             |-- abc: string (nullable = true)

But i want the same schema as the original df.

Comment: @Raj, I have updated the post with the desired output of yours.